# Excel VBA: How to create multiple Excel files using a single Excel template

Tags: vba, excel

My requirement is simple:

I have a list of filename in column `A:A200` of Sheet1 of Book1 and an Excel Book2 which is a readymade template with 6 sheets.

I need to create or rather replicate this excel Book2, by changing the file name of the template excel to the names I have in column `A:A200` of sheet1 of Book1.

Also a small functionality would be that the same name (name of the Excel or the name present in the column `A`) should be added to Sheet1, cell `B5` of the new sheet.

So basically I have to make copies of an excel template and rename them according to my list and also change a value in the new sheet as the name of the Excel.

Am sure many users would have wanted this simple functionality, so any small VBA code, or reference to any code already present would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out the example here](https://youtu.be/2R8wfpubr2E)

You can Down load the zipped Folder there as well to test and work with the code.